# Residuals formula with Xi

Tags: statistics

In the regression model: $Y=a+bX+e_i$, why is this formula correct:
$$\sum_{i=1}^nX_ie_i=0 $$ where $e_i$ is the residuals

Answer (score 1):

You can write the sum of squared error as $$ L = \sum_i (Y_i - (bX_i+ a))^2$$ and then the condition $$0= \sum_i X_ie_i = \sum_i X_i(Y_i-(b X_i +a)) $$ is the same as $$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial b} = 0,$$ one of the conditions that must hold for minimizing $L$.